# VB6 cannot add new form to project

Tags: vb6

In VB6 i cannot add a new form to an existing project which prompts me an error  "Project File i s read only "  the project is already added to the source safe. what issue causes that error. Is there any option to add the file to the project.

thank you

Comment: I would guess this causes the error *Project File is read only*. Remove read only from the project file.

Comment: @catcat already done by clicking folder properties of the project but not working same error, do u know any other options to remove read only

Comment: VB6 requires administrators permissions to run properly. Also the default save folder is the program file folder that requires administrators permissions to do that.

Comment: issue has been resolved, i need to be checked out the whole project then only i can add files.. thank u all for your supports

Answer (score 0):

I hate to state the obvious, but the project file contains a list of the classes, forms, and modules in your project.  So yes,m that file neess to be writable to add more files to your project.  Have you tried, using Windows Explorer, to right-click on you project file and select properties, and then uncheck the Read-Only flag?